# Field authorMongoRepository required a bean of type that could not be found

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, document

Description:

Field authorMongoRepository in com.example.SpringReturnObject.Mongo.Controller.AuthorController required a bean of type 'com.example.SpringReturnObject.Rest.Controller.AuthorMongoRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.SpringReturnObject.Rest.Controller.AuthorMongoRepository' in your configuration.
**AuthorMongoRepository class**
package com.example.SpringReturnObject.Rest.Controller;

```
import com.example.SpringReturnObject.Mongo.Model.Author;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface AuthorMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<Author, String> {

     List<Author> findByUsernameContainingIgnoreCase(String username);
     List<Author> findByArticles_titleContainingIgnoreCase(String title);
}
```

**AddnewDocument.java**
package com.example.SpringReturnObject.Mongo.Implementation;

```
import com.example.SpringReturnObject.Mongo.Model.Article;
import com.example.SpringReturnObject.Mongo.Model.Author;
import com.example.SpringReturnObject.Rest.Controller.AuthorMongoRepository;
import com.example.SpringReturnObject.Rest.Controller.MongoController;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class AddNewDoc implements MongoController {

    @Autowired
    AuthorMongoRepository authorMongoRepository;
    @Override
    public List<Author> getAllList() {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        authorMongoRepository.deleteAll();

        final Article article1;
        try {
            article1 = new Article("Spring Boot - MongoDB + Data + Web"
                    , "MongoDB", df.parse("10/5/2018"));
            final Article article2 = new Article("Spring Boot - MongoDB + Data + Web"
                    , "H2 Console", df.parse("2/3/2016"));
            final Article article3 = new Article("Spring Cloud - Zuul + Eureka + Rest Web", "Load Balancer with Zuul", df.parse("5/1/2018"));
            final Article article4 = new Article("Spring Cloud - Feign"
                    , "Feign Client + Eureka + Rest", df.parse("5/6/2018"));

            Author author1 = new Author("Melardev", Arrays.asList(article1, article2));
            Author author2 = new Author("Momo", Arrays.asList(article3, article4));

            authorMongoRepository.save(author1);
            authorMongoRepository.save(author2);
            
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**MongoControllerInterface**
package com.example.SpringReturnObject.Rest.Controller;

```
import com.example.SpringReturnObject.Mongo.Model.Author;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public interface MongoController {

    @GetMapping("/author")
    List<Author> getAllList();
}
```

**ApplicationStartup.java**
package com.example.SpringReturnObject;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.SpringReturnObject.Rest.Controller.AuthorMongoRepository")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.example.*"})
@EntityScan({"com.example.*"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringReturnObjectApplication  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringReturnObjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Should be repository base package in here: `@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.SpringReturnObject.Rest.Controller")` and not `@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.SpringReturnObject.Rest.Controller.AuthorMongoRepository")` which is the repository class itself

Comment: thank you but not resolved